# Suppose $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence of $M$-measurable functions on $X$. Let $p_1$ and $p_2\in [1,\infty)$, and suppose $f_k\in L^{p_1}\cap L^{p_2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Suppose $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence of $M$-measurable functions on $X$. Let $p_1$ and $p_2\in [1,\infty)$, and suppose $f_k\in L^{p_1}\cap L^{p_2}$. Also suppose there exist $g\in L^{p_1}$ and $h\in L^{p_2}$ such that $f_k\to g$ in $L^{p_1}$, $f_k\to h$ in $L^{p_2}$. Prove that $g=h$ ($\mu$ almost everywhere)

---

So we know $||f_k-g||_{p_1}\to 0$ and $||f_k-h||_{p_2}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. That means $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int |f_k-g|^{p_1}d\mu= 0$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int |f_k-h|^{p_2}d\mu= 0$.

Suppose it's valid to bring the limit inside the integral, and $\lim f_k$ exists (call it $f$). Then $\int|f-g|^{p_1}d\mu=\int|f-h|^{p_2}d\mu=0$. That means $f=g=h$ almost everywhere. But how do I justify bringing the limit inside and $\lim f_k$ exists? Can I apply dominated convergence theorem? Is $|f_k-g|$ bounded?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence in $L^p$ spaces implies convergence in measure. Then 
$$f_k\to g\quad\text{and}\quad f_k\to f$$
in measure. By the [uniqueness](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/409903/8271) of the limit of sequences of functions which converges in measure, we can conclude $f = g$ almos everywhere.

Note: Uniqueness of the limit of sequences which converges in measure is a consequence of the Hausdorffness of the topology of "convergence in measure". In general, if a space is Hausdorff then the limits of sequences are unique.

---

Alternatively:

Since $f_k\to g$ in $L^{p_1}$, there exist a subsequence $(f_{k_j})_j$ such that $f_{k_j}\to g$ pointwise a.e.

Since $f_k\to h$ in $L^{p_2}$, its subsequence $(f_{k_j})_j$ must converge to $h$ as well in $L^{p_2}$.

Since $f_{k_j}\to h$ in $L^{p_2}$, there exist a subsequence $(f_{k_{j_i}})_i$ which converges to $h$ pointwise a.e.

Since $(f_{k_{j_i}})_i$ is a subsequence of $(f_{k_j})_j$ and $f_{k_j}\to g$ pointwise a.e., it follows that $f_{k_{j_i}}\to g$ pointwise a.e.

So, in the set of pointwise convergence of $(f_{k_{j_i}})_i$ we have $g = h$. But this set is the whole space without a set of measure zero, i.e. $g=h$ a.e.

Comment: Can this be proved without using Hausdorffness? We haven't learned it yet. Thanks.

Comment: @YifengXu Yes, click on "uniqueness" in my answer.

Comment: @YifengXu is there something unclear?

Comment: Why does converence in $L^p$ spaces imply convergence in measure? We haven't talked about convergence in measure yet. Thank you!

Comment: @YifengXu edited

Comment: @YifengXu If you liked this answer or any of the other answers provided by the other users then you can click the check mark beside the answer to "accept" it. If you have 15 rep or above, then you can even upvote an answer to show gratitude; you can upvote multiple answers. This will help the user and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a simpler way to say it.  If $f_k \to g$ in $L^{p_1}$, then there exists a subsequence $f_{k_n} \to g$ a.e.

Answer (score 0):

$f_k \to g$ in measure, and $f_k \to h$ in measure.  And the topology of "convergence in measure" is Hausdorff.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure

To show the latter, note that if $f_k \to g$ in measure, then there is a subsequence $f_{k_n}$ that converges a.e. to $g$.

Comment: Can this be proved without resorting to Hausdorff? We haven't learned it yet. Thanks.